# Como resolver problemas no upload do TIdFTP no Object-Pascal?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, object-pascal

Descobri um jeito de fazer uploads no meu server FTP, porém tento notado que arquivos com peso superior a 1 KB chegam danificados, então peço a ajuda de vocês para resolver meu problema, o modo utilizado em questão foi o da imagem abaixo, como resolver este problema?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

na propriedade TransferType qual das duas opções você selecionou?

Somente selecione o ftascii quando for algum arquivo texto, pas, algo assim.
Nos demais trabalhe com ftBinary, .exe, fotos, etc.